# Magento 1.9.2.4 media uploader freezes browser

Tags: magento-1.9, uploader

When I want to add an image to a page or static block I use the media gallery and upload a new image.

Unfortunately, when I press the browse button I can select a file. But as soon as I select it, it freezes in all browsers.

I know the media uploader has been updated not to use flash anymore, which is a great improvement. But It suddenly stopped working, and I am not sure how to debug this kind of problem using the inspector.

Comment: When you say "I know the media uploader has been updated not to use flash anymore" that means you have applied SUPEE-8788 right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @RaphaelatDigitalPianism

Comment: I have a small update; it appears to be a server-side issue. When I run the Magento install locally, it works fine, and also when I move the install to the server it freezes all browsers again! Still not sure of what is causing this!

Comment: Another small update for everyone else experience this. I have reuploaded the /js/ directory and everything seems to be working fine again.

Comment: @xvilo I am getting the same issue on the server but it is working correctly  on local system

Comment: @SaphalJha like I said in mijn previous comment, try to re-upload your /js/ directory. I solved my issue....

Comment: @xvilo : I applied it but not working. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue with increasing value of **post_max_size** in php.ini

If still get the issue, you should check the value of **chunkSize** in js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for sharing. The bug is still weird though.

Comment: @xvilo Install  php-gd  and try again and let me know the result please. :)